# How many solutions are there to the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 \leq 35$ in which all the $x_i$ are non-negative integers?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, problem-solving

So I know how to solve these kinds of problems in general using the stars and bars approach. We treat the variables as the "slots" where we can deposit stars as our "counters", and there are $3$ bars. It then turns into a permutation over multisets.

But I'm struggling with this problem in particular because it completely deviates from what I'm familiar with, as we're no longer depositing exactly $35$ stars but less than or equal to $35$:

> How many solutions are there to the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 \leq 35$ in which all the $x_i$ are non-negative integers? (Hint: add an extra variable y such that y is non-negative and $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + y = 35$)

Still not sure how to solve it, even with the hint. I also don't see how the hint is relevant. The answer key says the following:

> The number of solutions to
>
> (1)     $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 \leq 35$
>
> with all the $x_i$ non-negative integers is equal to the number of solutions to
>
> (2)     $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + y = 35$
>
> with all the $x_i$ and $y$ non-negative integers.

Why is this true?

Comment: $y$ is the deficit between $35$ and $\sum_{i=1}^4x_i$. So if you add the deficit then the two sides are equal.

Comment: If $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 \le 35$, then $35 - (x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4) \ge 0$.  Call that difference $y$.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Yeah, I don't know what any of that means :P

Comment: Instead of writing mathematica code @DavidG.Stork, it would be more beneficial to reference [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) and give the analytical solution of $\binom{35+5-1}{5-1}=\binom{39}{4}=82251$, the number of solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4\leq 35$ and $\binom{35+4-1}{4-1}=8436$, the number of solutions to $x_1+\dots+x_4=35$.  I'm sure your numbers are off.  Note that it specifies *non-negative* and that it specifies that order of values matters.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork the number of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $35$ into $5$ parts [is indeed $674$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partitions+of+35), but this counts the scenario where $x_1\leq x_2\leq x_3\leq x_4\leq y$ which is not at all necessary here.  A more correct term to search here is [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)), but note that care needs to be made if you describe this problem with compositions since in compositions we require each term to be strictly positive but here we allow zeroes.

Comment: Saying $“a\le b”$ is the same as saying $“a+c=b$ for some nonnegative integer $c”$

Comment: To me is not at all obvious that the solutions are $\binom{35+4+1}{4+1}=82251$. Experts should sometimes wear other people's shoes :)

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Thank you for that, it's much easier for me to now visualize what Anurag meant by "deficit". You're adding "c" to _make up_ for the fact that "a" is less than "b". So in this case, we added "y" to force the inequality to become an equality by letting "y" be the deficit. Perfect, thank you!